# RxJava 2.0 - How to convert Observable to Publisher

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactivex, reactive-streams, rx-java2

How to convert Observable to Publisher in RxJava version 2?

In the first version we have the https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaReactiveStreams project that do exactly what I need.
But How can I do it in RxJava 2?

Comment: Convert it to Flowable as it implements Publisher.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
Publisher publisher = observable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.XXX);
```

As `Observable` does not implement backpressure, you need to select backpressure strategy when converting. See available choices [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/BackpressureStrategy.html).

Or use `Flowable` instead of `Observable` in the first place. See [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable) for details.